# camera input output at GRUB

Tags: grub2, camera

Though complete naive thought and may seem headless but i was thinking that is it possible (by limited means) to have my camera input in a small box @ GRUB boot screen where we have to select choices to select an OS?

Answer (score 0):

Grub does not have the ability of that type of rendering itself. By design is text based only but can load a background if enabled. It does not load any device drivers for hardware. IE: webcam

Comment: thnx a lot for the info, are there other bootloaders or any piece of software which when enabled directly loads the drivers to the webcam? Like is there any way to achieve the following: 1. You power on your PC 2. Dell splash is produced 3. The webcam input is displayed 4. then you click a key and you are led to the GRUB screen?